# Google Sheet custom Dialog - Splash screen not displaying body text

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a splash screen in Google sheets using a Custom Dialog with the following code:

```
let htmlOutput = HtmlService
   .createHtmlOutput('<p><font size="4" face="arial">' + msgTextHTML + '</font></p>')
   .setWidth(width)
   .setHeight(height);
ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, titleText);
```

When the code executes the custom dialog is displayed but only with the title text, the body text is only displayed after a significant delay.  As far as I can tell, it is waiting until after the script has completed before displaying the body text and is thus not a very good splash screen.  Is there any way I can force it to display the body text immediately?

Comment: It seems that when HTML is used, the display speed is a bit slow. Although, unfortunately, I'm not sure whether this method is included in your goal, in this case, for example, how about using `alert` like `ui.alert(msgTextHTML)` instead of `ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "titleText")`? But, if this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I don't think ui.alert will work because I want to use it as a splash screen and thus when the script is done I need to make it disappear programmatically

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: I have tested your code and the text appears less than a second after activating the function. Is that the delay you are referring to?

Comment: How do you propose to make the splash screen "disappear programmatically"?  I would propose you use HTML template with scriptlet to substitute `msgTextHTML ` and have a `<script>` to close it.

Comment: What is the purpose of the splash screen? Have you considered to use a [Spreadsheet.toast()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg) instead?